# What are the two parts to a compound word?

Tags: compounds

I'm wondering what each word that compromise a compound word is called. For example, You would say:

> "Life" is the first ____ in "lifetime". There are two ____s in "lifetime".

Is the answer I am looking for simply "word", or is there another word for this?

Additionally, would a name be considered the same? For example, if someone were named "Hammerfist", would you say that this name is a compound word and would the same rule listed above apply here?

Comment: They are called 'bases'.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

"Lifetime" is a compound. "Life" is the first **root** in "lifetime". There are two **roots** in "lifetime".

See the [definition of compound](http://www.glossary.sil.org/term/compound) in SIL's Glossary of Linguistic Terms, which defines a **compound** as "a word containing a stem that is made up of more than one root."